# pip/tensorflow stopped working on upgrade: enum error

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, pip

The last thing I tried doing was upgrading tensorflow manually on the cmd line:

```
pip install --user tensorflow==1.4.1
```

After the update, I keep getting this error, I can not use pip for any other installs or run any code with tensorflow:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python36\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "c:\python36\lib\re.py", line 142, in <module>
    class RegexFlag(enum.IntFlag):
AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: The problem is that [tensorflow depends on enum34](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/15136), which is only needed for Python 3.4 and below. When you installed tensorflow, it installed enum34 too, and for some reason that ended up before the built-in `enum` in `sys.path`. I had this same issue recently. I fixed it by running `pip uninstall enum34`. If you can't run that, you should manually delete the enum34 installation directory (probably `C:/Python36/Lib/site-packages/enum`). You might want to then run the uninstallation command to make sure it's fully uninstalled.

Comment: I deleted the 'enum34-1.1.6' folder but that did not fix it

Comment: You mean "enum34-1.1.6.dist-info"? That's just information about the package. There should be an "enum" folder in that directory. That's the one you need to delete.

Comment: deleted it, that seemed to fix my problem.ty